# I'm trying to make a custom progress bar with an image, but I'm not sure where to start

Tags: php, html, css, progress-bar

My main goal is to have an image at the end of a progress bar, so that when the progress bar moves, the image moves with it.

I've used the standard progress bar code from HTML, but I'm not super well versed in HTML so I'm not sure how I could change it to have an image.

This is the bar code in my main file.

```
<h3 id="progress2">Progress</h3>
<progress id="progress" value="<?php echo $total1 ?>" max="<?php echo $pracGoal ?>">
</progress>
```

total1 and pracGoal are both variable that are meant to be the current value and maximum of the bar. Below is my css code in a separate sytlesheet.

```
#Progress{
    width: 50%;
    background-color:#ddd;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:110px;
}
```

Currently, I'm just getting the standard HTML progress bar. However, my goal is to get something like the progress bar, but with a picture of a rabbit at the end of the bar or something along those lines that moves with the progress bar.

Comment: First of all in HTML an ID should only be used once otherwise you should use `class`. Have you tried to set `background-image: url("your_image_path");` instead of the color? Then you would have that image as the background of you progress bar.

Comment: That didn't really work, it just changed the background of the bar, not added the image to the end of the bar. Also edited the header id to be different, didn't notice that at first, nice catch.

Comment: Oh you'd like to have the image as the current status of the progress bar? So that it moves the image to the right when the progress value increases? I can't help you with that but maybe you'll find something here: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the question.